# Необработанное исключение: System.ObjectDisposedException: Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен

Tags: c#

У меня есть клиент и сервер. Вот код клиента:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Json;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Lab3Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private TcpClient client;

        private StreamReader reader;
        private StreamWriter writer;

        private bool isConnected;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5555);

            HandleCommunication();
        }

        private void HandleCommunication()
        {
            reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            isConnected = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AddWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AddWorker_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Worker worker = new Worker(Name.Text, Position.Text, long.Parse(Salary.Text));
            string workerData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(worker);

            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest
            {
                ActionType = 0,
                Payload = workerData
            };

            string data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

            if (isConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(data);
                    writer.Flush();
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }

            }

        }

        private void ShowAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest
            {
                ActionType = 1,
            };

            string data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

            if (isConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(data);
                    writer.Flush();

                    string serverResponse = reader.ReadLine();
                    WorkersArray workers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WorkersArray>(serverResponse);

                    string output = "";

                    workers.Workers.ForEach(worker =>
                    {
                        output += worker.Name + " " + worker.Position + " " + worker.Salary + "\r\n";
                    });

                    SearchAllOutput.Text = output;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }

            }

        }

        private void SearchByName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest
            {
                ActionType = 2,
                Payload = WorkerName.Text
            };

            string data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

            if (isConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(data);
                    writer.Flush();

                    string serverResponse = reader.ReadLine();
                    WorkersArray workers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WorkersArray>(serverResponse);

                    string output = "";

                    workers.Workers.ForEach(worker =>
                    {
                        output += worker.Name + " " + worker.Position + " " + worker.Salary + "\r\n";
                    });

                    SearchAllOutput.Text = output;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }

            }

        }

        private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest
            {
                ActionType = 3,
                Payload = WorkerName.Text
            };

            string data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

            if (isConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(data);
                    writer.Flush();

                    string serverResponse = reader.ReadLine();
                    WorkersArray workers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WorkersArray>(serverResponse);

                    string output = "";

                    workers.Workers.ForEach(worker =>
                    {
                        output += worker.Name + " " + worker.Position + " " + worker.Salary + "\r\n";
                    });

                    SearchAllOutput.Text = output;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }

            }


        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest
            {
                ActionType = 4,
            };

            string data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

            if (isConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(data);
                    writer.Flush();

                    string serverResponse = reader.ReadLine();
                    WorkersArray workers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WorkersArray>(serverResponse);

                    string output = "";

                    workers.Workers.ForEach(worker =>
                    {
                        output += worker.Name + " " + worker.Position + " " + worker.Salary + "\r\n";
                    });

                    SearchAllOutput.Text = output;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }

            }

        }

        private void Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Worker newWorker = new Worker(NewName.Text, NewPosition.Text, long.Parse(NewSalary.Text));
            EditWorkerRequest editWorkerRequest = new EditWorkerRequest
            {
                NewWorker = newWorker,
                OldName = OldName.Text
            };

            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest
            {
                ActionType = 5,
                Payload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(editWorkerRequest)                
            };

            string data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

            if (isConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(data);
                    writer.Flush();

                    string serverResponse = reader.ReadLine();
                    WorkersArray workers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WorkersArray>(serverResponse);

                    string output = "";

                    workers.Workers.ForEach(worker =>
                    {
                        output += worker.Name + " " + worker.Position + " " + worker.Salary + "\r\n";
                    });

                    SearchAllOutput.Text = output;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }

            }

        }
    }

    class Worker
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public long Salary { get; set; }

        public Worker(string name, string position, long salary)
        {
            Name = name;
            Position = position;
            Salary = salary;
        }
    }

    class WorkersArray
    {
        public List<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
    }

    class ServerRequest
    {
        public int ActionType { get; set; }
        public string Payload { get; set; }
    }

    class ServerResponse
    {
        public string Response { get; set; }
    }

    class EditWorkerRequest
    {
        public string OldName { get; set; }
        public Worker NewWorker { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Вот код сервера:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;


namespace Lab3Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private bool isRunning;
        private TcpListener tcpListener;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeTcp()
        {
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5555);
            tcpListener.Start();
            isRunning = true;

            LoopClients();
        }

        private void LoopClients()
        {

            while (isRunning)
            {
                TcpClient newClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
                thread.Start(newClient);
            }

        }

        private void HandleClient(object obj)
        {
            TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;

            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            bool isClientConnected = true;
            string clientData = null;

            while (isClientConnected)
            {
                clientData = streamReader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Data: " + clientData);

                ServerRequest request = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ServerRequest>(clientData);

                if (request.ActionType == 0)
                {
                    AddWorker(request.Payload);
                } else if (request.ActionType == 1)
                {
                    GetWorkers(client);
                } else if (request.ActionType == 2)
                {
                    SearchWorker(request.Payload, client);
                } else if (request.ActionType == 3)
                {
                    DeleteWorker(request.Payload, client);
                } else if (request.ActionType == 4)
                {
                    SortBySalary(client);
                } else if (request.ActionType == 5)
                {
                    EditWorker(request.Payload, client);
                }
            }
        }

        private void EditWorker(string payload, TcpClient client)
        {
            EditWorkerRequest request = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EditWorkerRequest>(payload);
            Worker newWorker = request.NewWorker;

            string line;
            List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"E:\Лабы\7 сем\рис\Lab3\Lab3Server\text.txt");

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                workers.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Worker>(line));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < workers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (workers[i].Name.Equals(request.OldName))
                {
                    workers[i] = newWorker;
                }
            }

            WorkersArray arr = new WorkersArray()
            {
                Workers = workers
            };

            reader.Close();

            writer.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(arr));
            writer.Close();

        }

        private void SortBySalary(TcpClient client)
        {
            string line;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"E:\Лабы\7 сем\рис\Lab3\Lab3Server\text.txt");
            List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                workers.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Worker>(line));
            }

            reader.Close();

            IEnumerable<Worker> query = workers.OrderBy(worker => worker.Salary);
            workers = query.ToList();

            WorkersArray arr = new WorkersArray()
            {
                Workers = workers
            };

            reader.Close();

            writer.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(arr));
            writer.Close();
        }

        private void DeleteWorker(string name, TcpClient client)
        {
            string line;
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"E:\Лабы\7 сем\рис\Lab3\Lab3Server\text.txt");
            List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                workers.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Worker>(line));
            }

            reader.Close();

            workers = workers.FindAll(worker => !worker.Name.Equals(name));

            WorkersArray arr = new WorkersArray()
            {
                Workers = workers
            };

            string workersStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(arr);

            writer.Write(workersStr);
            writer.Flush();

            File.WriteAllText(@"E:\Лабы\7 сем\рис\Lab3\Lab3Server\text.txt", workersStr);
        }

        private void SearchWorker(string payload, TcpClient client)
        {
            string line;
            List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"E:\Лабы\7 сем\рис\Lab3\Lab3Server\text.txt");

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                workers.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Worker>(line));
            }

            workers = workers.FindAll(worker => worker.Name.Equals(payload));

            WorkersArray arr = new WorkersArray()
            {
                Workers = workers
            };

            writer.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(arr));
            writer.Close();

            reader.Close();
        }

        private void GetWorkers(TcpClient client)
        {
            string line;
            List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"E:\Лабы\7 сем\рис\Lab3\Lab3Server\text.txt");

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                workers.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Worker>(line));
            }

            WorkersArray arr = new WorkersArray()
            {
                Workers = workers
            };

            writer.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(arr));
            writer.Close();

            reader.Close();
        }

        private void AddWorker(string worker)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"E:\Лабы\7 сем\рис\Lab3\Lab3Server\text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

            streamWriter.WriteLine(worker);
            streamWriter.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeTcp();
        }
    }

    class Worker
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public long Salary { get; set; }

        public Worker(string name, string position, long salary)
        {
            Name = name;
            Position = position;
            Salary = salary;
        }
    }

    class ServerRequest
    {
        public int ActionType { get; set; }
        public string Payload { get; set; }
    }

    class ServerResponse
    {
        public string Response { get; set; }
    }

    class WorkersArray
    {
        public List<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
    }

    class EditWorkerRequest
    {
        public string OldName { get; set; }
        public Worker NewWorker { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Когда я в клиенте нажимаю кнопку получить всех рабочих (GetWorkers в сервере), то срабатывает ObjectAlreadyDisposedException в методе HandleClient. До этого пробовал заменить во всех методах сервера writer.close на writer.flush, но в таком случае сервер отправлял данные, а клиент их почему-то не получал. Понимаю, что проблема в том, что я уничтожаю каким-то образом объект, но как по другому отправить данные клиенту не знаю. Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: при уничтожении сборщиком мусора, что `StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);`, что `StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);` попытаются закрыть поток `client.GetStream()`. Чтобы они поток оставили открытым, надо использовать другую перегрузку конструктора для читателя и писателя - там есть перегрузка, что в конце bool принимает.

Comment: Помог ли вам мой ответ?

Answer (score 1):

`StreamWriter` и `StreamWriter` закрывают переданный им поток, как только уничтожаются. Так как вы вручную не уничтожаете (не вызываете `.Dispose()` для двух классов в этом методе, их уничтожает (финализирует) Garbage Collector, что вызывает закрытие потока `TcpClient` дважды, при этом второе закрытие подряд как раз и выдает то самое исключение. Нельзя закрыть уже закрытый поток.

Изучите, [как надо правильно работать с классами, реализующими `IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).

Для удобства использования `IDisposable` есть ключевое слово `using`. Ниже приведенный код показывает, как это выглядит. Теперь объекты диспозятся в коде, а не где-то там сборщиком мусора, это правильно, так положено делать, чтобы код был предсказуемым.

Но как я вижу, именно в этом методе вам не нужно закрывать поток `TcpClient`, поэтому в конструкторы этих двух классов я передаю параметр `leaveOpen = true`, это сообщает `StreamReader` и `StreamWriter`, что они должны оставить переданный им поток открытым при уничтожении.

```cs
private void HandleClient(object obj)
{
    using (TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj)
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII, leaveOpen: true))
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII, leaveOpen: true))
    {

        bool isClientConnected = true;
        string clientData = null;

        while (isClientConnected)
        {
            clientData = streamReader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Data: " + clientData);

            ServerRequest request = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ServerRequest>(clientData);

            if (request.ActionType == 0)
            {
                AddWorker(request.Payload);
            }
            else if (request.ActionType == 1)
            {
                GetWorkers(client);
            }
            else if (request.ActionType == 2)
            {
                SearchWorker(request.Payload, client);
            }
            else if (request.ActionType == 3)
            {
                DeleteWorker(request.Payload, client);
            }
            else if (request.ActionType == 4)
            {
                SortBySalary(client);
            }
            else if (request.ActionType == 5)
            {
                EditWorker(request.Payload, client);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Реализуйте `using` во всех остальных частях когда, используйте `leaveOpen`, когда используемый поток не нужно закрывать, в вашем случае - везде, где используется `client.GetStream()`. Поток закроет тот `using`, который у `TcpClient`.

Схема такая:

**Было**

```cs
StreamReader sr = ...
// ваш код
sr.Close();
```

**Стало**

```cs
using (StreamReader sr = ...)
{
    // ваш код
}
```

Так же внимательно перечитайте код, например в методе `SortBySalary` вы вызываете 2 раза `reader.Close()`, повторюсь - так не надо делать.